# index() match() join() I want to show all duplicate results disregarding their order

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a formula to make volunteer-task scheduling easier. In the database I have lists with volunteer names that have chosen specific tasks and specific timeslots.

I wrote a formula to match tasks and timeslots and show me all matching names in the same cell, joined by "," as a separator. The cells would show, for example, all volunteers that have chosen timeslot1 and task5.

The results of these will be table crossing all tasks and timeslots.

My problem is: I want to compare two `INDEX()MATCH()` results and show only and all of the duplicate results. Right now it is only showing the results that are in the same order. Meaning: If Sara is result #1 after the first `INDEX()MATCH()`, it will *only* be shown if it is result #1 after the second `INDEX()MATCH()`.

Here is the formula:

```
=join(", ", filter(index($C$22:$H$26, match(E9, $B$22:$B$26)),index($C$22:$H$26, match(E9, $B$22:$B$26))=index($C$17:$H$21, match(D10, $B$17:$B$21))))
```

Here is the link to the document. I tried to explain further there:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qjDfqpOMeJEelqRGFOwk5dKuzB7pB14OY_g0cjljrB4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would filter based on [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292). The regular expression would be the join of one of two rows. Suppose the names are in rows 4 and 5, and columns E through J. I'm using row 5 to make a regular expression, joining the names with "or" symbol `|`:

```
="^("&JOIN("|", FILTER(E5:J5, LEN(E5:J5)))&")$"
```

This returns "Lars|Anairis|Emil|Johan|Leela". Note I'm filtering out any blank cells to avoid getting `||` in regular expression, which would match anything. Also, the ^ and $ symbols ensure that only the entire string will match.

Then filter row 4 by the above regular expression (replaced with ... for readability):

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(E4:J4, REGEXMATCH(E4:J4, ... )))
```

This returns "Leela, Anairis, Lars", which is the desired result.

When put together, the whole formula is somewhat scary:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(E4:J4, REGEXMATCH(E4:J4, "^("&JOIN("|", FILTER(E5:J5, LEN(E5:J5)))&")$")))
```